# MySQL select all and add custom field

Tags: mysql

My current SQL query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM devices GROUP BY name ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

I use `SELECT *` because I need most of the fields and I don't want to add all field names one by one. (Prformance isn't important in this issue)

But I also add a custom field to results like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "times_added", * FROM devices GROUP BY name
      ORDER BY login_number DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

But latter query doesn't work. Can I add a count field and get all fields from table ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT devices.*, COUNT(*) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the rows with the count value try this query

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM devices)AS times_added
FROM devices 
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY login_number DESC 
LIMIT 0,100
```

If you want the 1st row values along with the count value only, try this

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS times_added
FROM devices 
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY login_number DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The [reference documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) states that:

> Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may
>   produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified
>   tbl_name.* reference

so do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "times_added", devices.* 
FROM devices 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY login_number DESC 
LIMIT 0,100
```